# How to make VSTO outlook add on trusted

Tags: c#, vsto

HI I have made an out look addin using 2013 and planning to deploy on windows 8.1.  But it gives me an error that the addin in not trusted and cannot be install . I will be grateful if anyone can tell how to make it trusted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using ClickOnce to deploy your addin.

In this case you will have to sign the manifest by using a certificate.

Try to sign it by following the steps in this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772096.aspx

You can also refer to here for more information on signing and trusting VSTO solutions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772086.aspx#signing